# Matlab gradient when missing variables

Tags: matlab, gradient

Let a function `f` depending of a symbolic variable vector of length 5, `x`. I want to derive the symbolic gradient of `f`.

```
c=1
d=2
x=sym('x',[1 5]);
f=-0.5*log(x(1))+x(1)*0.5*(x(2+d)/x(1)-c)^2
gradient(f)
```

It gives a vector of length 2 because some variables are missing in `f`. Is it possible to have a vector of length 5 with 0 when the variable is missing in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy as telling `gradient` which are the symbolic variables:

`gradient(f,x)`

> ```
> ans =
>
>  (x4/x1 - 1)^2/2 - 1/(2*x1) - (x4*(x4/x1 - 1))/x1
>                                                 0
>                                                 0
>                                         x4/x1 - 1
>                                                 0
> ```

Comment: @AnthonyHauser Consider accepting the asnwer as valid then (by clicking in the green tick)

Comment: Just a small info in addition: The second parameter `v` is optional and will be derived like this: `By default, v is a vector constructed from all symbolic variables found in f. The order of variables in this vector is defined by symvar.` (https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html) Exactly the issue @AnthonyHauser is encountering because his `f` only contains 2 sym-variables :-)

Comment: How can I change x in order to have a function whose variables are x=(x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5)) instead of x1, x2, x3,x4,x5?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser `x(1)` is not a valid symbolic variable in MATLAB

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ok, thanks. Do you know how to tranform x1 into x(1) x2 into x(2) etc?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser you are being very unclear. In your code `x(1)` *is already* `x1`. Try typing x(1) in the command line.

Comment: I think @AnthonyHauser wants to replace the literal `xn` with `x(n)` in the expression so when `gradient(f)` is `matlabFunction`-ed, it can be called with a single, standard `double` array without much fuss.  Which, if that's the case, is an entirely separate question.

Comment: Yes it is exactly that Troy

Comment: @AnthonyHauser then, accept this question, and ask an entire separate question in stackoverflow.